# How to make product gallery thumbs over the image in Magento 2? Like in this example

Tags: gallery, fotorama

I am able to do it vertically but how can I get it over the image? Magento 2.3.4

[image: gallery]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `position: absolute;` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

1. Ensure there is a parent for both the gallery and the thumbnails
2. Set the parent's `position` to `relative`;
3. Set the thumbnails `position` to `absolute` and then use `top` and `left` to position it where you want it.

Comment: I thought fotorama has some customization options. Css helped. Thank you!